# Encryption through multiplication of encoded key

Tags: encryption, keys

Yesterday I finished programming my own encryption program. It is using an input and a key. Here are all the steps it is going through. For an example, let say the `input is "Hello"` and the `key is "Hi"`

1. You take the input and convert it into binary:

`01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111`

2. You make this Binary string into one long string:

   `0100100001100101011011000110110001101111`
3. You convert this long binary number into a decimal number:

   `0100100001100101011011000110110001101111 = 310939249775`
4. You do the same 3 steps above with the key. So the key "Hi" in Decimal is:

   `18537`
5. You now take the length of the key, in this 2 because "Hi" has 2 characters.
6. You multiply the two decimal value, and multiply that by the length of the key:

   `310939249775*18537*2 = 11527761746158350`
7. You lastly convert this big number into Base36(0-9 a-z). This is the final output:

   `35i90mxoaa6`

Now this is how my encryption program works. You can reverse this my dividing the numbers. If someone only has the output but not the key, he has no way to get to the original message right? Also, if this doesn't exist, can I name this the way I want?

Comment: I'd guess even with just the output, yes it is possible to decrypt quite quickly. But biggest problem is that a "known plaintext" attack would be highly effective - almost trivial, even if you only know a few characters of the plaintext, to use that to derive the key.

Comment: Also re-using the same key is dangerous, since any differences between successive values will also contain a multiple of the key (and differences between these differences etc), so each message seen will reduce the effort required to simply factorise out the key.

Answer (score 2):

It is insecure in the sense that anybody with a calculator can reverse it (and a large set of people without one).

According to the Kerckhoff principle you should tell everybody the algorithm. So there is no security there.

After that an attacker will receive multiple ciphertext (ciphertext only attack). This attacker will quickly find a common divisor for the ciphertext. This common divisor is the key.

Furthermore, there are special values in your plaintext. In principle you don't want to have these in a cryptographic algorithm. Say for instance that you send a single space. In that case you would send bit string `00100000`. As you can see there is only one bit set. Multiplication will result in a binary representation of the key "Hi", shifted 5 bits to the left. So an attacker can simply read the key straight from memory. If you can think of such a value, then your cipher is already considered broken.

Finally, a good cipher is a random permutation; a 1:1 mapping of the key to the ciphertext. That's the case in your algorithm, but the permutation is from $N$ to a set $key \times N$. Now you would have to encode this ciphertext efficiently or you end up with very large ciphertext values. This is why most cryptography uses modular arithmetic and XOR (which can be thought of as addition modulus 2).

Comment: Note that I've answered so you can understand some basic principles for encryption. This Q/A site is not for helping you design algorithms iteratively. Try to understand some basics first, like the Caesar cipher and Vigenère cipher.